# How do I require a library in PLT scheme (pre-racket)?

Tags: racket

I need to use a [PLT-scheme library](http://download.plt-scheme.org/mrspidey/) that only runs on a very old version of DrScheme (DrScheme v103p1), which I think is from at least 15 years ago.

The problem I am having is that I can't figure out how to use the library in my code because aparently the "require" function from modern racket didn't exist back then. What do I have to do to use a library then? All I know for now is that the file containing the definitions I want resides on "C:\Program Files\PLT\collects\mzlib\spidey.ss".

I tried using `(require "spidey.ss")` and `(require "spidey")` but both failed with a `reference to unidentified identifier: required` error.

Comment: Oh jeez. Why do you need to run this?

Comment: For research. The code I want to run is a static analyser for LISP and I want to compare it with more modern stuff :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `require-library` to load things from the standard library:

http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/103p1/html/mzscheme/node157.htm

```
(require-library "spidey.ss")
```

You can also use the support facilities (load and friends) to load single files. You need to use absolute paths though or else its going to search relative to your current working directory.

http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/103p1/html/mzscheme/node149.htm

```
(load "C:/Program Files/PLT/collects/mzlib/spidey.ss")
```

---

Since MrSpidey is integrated into DrScheme, open DrScheme and then follow these instructions:

http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/103p1/html/mrspidey/node4.htm

Comment: Thank you! `load` works but by searching the rest of the manual you linked to I found out that `require-library` is more appropriate to my needs.

Comment: TIL there was a "MrSpidey".

Comment: @GregHendershott: I think you are going to like how the [logo](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kIMKe.gif) and [UI](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wkUdn.png) look like then.